# Neo4j why picking a single node and a single edge take so long?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to test the speed of Neo4j, thus I created an empty database and then populate it with 10,000 users.

Now I run the following query

```
MATCH (n) RETURN id(n) LIMIT 1;
```

Surprisingly, it takes 1069 ms!

Then I run the following query (note: I haven't created any edges)

```
MATCH ()-[r]-() RETURN id(r) LIMIT 1;
```

which takes 1153ms!

Then I run

```
MATCH (n) RETURN id(n) SKIP 9900 LIMIT 100
```

which takes 10427ms.

Is it normal? I think those operations, at least the last one, is quite frequent in an app. I am using a Macbook Air with 1.7GHz Core i5

Answer (score 2):

What version of Neo4j are you using?

How do you measure? The Neo4j browser measures multiple roundtrips for additional data.

Also is that the first or a subsequent query?

None of those queries should be that slow. Perhaps you can share your Neo4j configuration?

1. that one should be really fast
2. this one goes over all the nodes (or even over the cross product) in your graph and tries to find a relationship at the end it doesn't find any
3. that one should also be really fat.

Regarding your comment, if you know the first node, your search will be anchored and you don't have to scan all rels in the database.

```
MATCH (:User {name:"Han"})-[:FRIEND]->(friend)
RETURN friend
```

Comment: Hi, I am using the 2.03 version. I measured them from neo4j-shell. I ran the 1 and 3 again, the results are 156ms and 534ms. I noticed that the first time I was running right after creating seed data by running 10,000 CREATE operations, which I guess may cause the database to slow down. But does it on the other side saying that the database cannot perform efficiently after large amount of (almost simultaneously ) writing? Besides, I think 156ms for 1 is still not fast (but in fact moments ago I just created some edges using batch operations, is this the reason?)

Comment: Also, you mentioned that in (2), the query will go over ALL nodes (or even product) to search for relationships? What if in the real world, I want to find a friend of a user, say A, but A has no friend at all. Then it will take that long to return the result?

Comment: Update. I blieve there is indeed something strange. I restarted my computer, and even waited it to cool down. Then I ran the first query again, it takes 2241ms. Then I ran again, this time takes 181ms (I think due to cache). So why does the first time take so long?

Comment: Caches need to warm up. First invocation is mostly driven the speed of your IO subsystem.